# Is it possible to determine the date a particular .NET Framework version was installed on Windows Server?

Tags: .net-4.0

Is it possible to determine the date on which a particular version of the .NET Framework was first installed on a Windows Server?

Answer (score 1):

You've not mentioned a version of Windows so I went with 2019. Settings, Apps and Features, Programs and Features will show the "Installed on date."

[image]

Comment: On our server, the .NET Framework installations are not appearing in Programs and Features.

Comment: Do you know the windows version?

Comment: Windows Server 2016 Standard